# Laptop won't boot No POST

Tags: dell-inspiron, post

I have a dell inspiron 15r SE, it's less than a week old.
The windows was locked (and i forgot the password) so i figured i'll restart and reset the password from safe mode. but it seemed that something was preventing it from restart (probably some of my stuff i was working on) so i forced a restart.

Now the laptop won't go past the Dell screen i can access the setup and the boot screens
i have nothing attached to the laptop and i've run a diagnostic test from boot screen didn't detect any errors (running a through test now will take some time)

i've tried removing the battery or just booting from the battery no change.

Comment: Does the hard drive show up in the setup and/or diagnostics?  How long have you let it sit at the Dell screen, waiting for it to boot? Can you boot from a LiveCD or alike?

Comment: yes the hard drive shows up in both
i left it at that screen for about 30 minutes
i haven't tried booting from a livecd (don't have one at the moment)

Comment: Well you'll either need the tools to further diagnose (LiveCD, etc.) or you're going to have to take it to someone who does.  As @theUser1024 points out, if it's that new then it's under warranty, so take it back to where you got it and/or contact Dell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call Dells Support Hotline since it should still be under warranty.